# Can I get the path of a .bbappend file?

Tags: linux, git, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have a `.bbappend` file within a custom Yocto Project layer (and separate repo).

I would like to place information about my custom layer (e.g. git stuff for my custom repo/layer) within a file that this `.bbappend` modifies.

Any commands which are run from this `.bbappend` are run as if from the `.bb` file to which it appends (the `.bb` is in another layer and repo [as recommended](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#other-recommendations)).

I thought there might be some hope for running `VAR := "stuff ${OTHER_VAR} more"`, which [some documentation](http://elinux.org/Bitbake_Cheat_Sheet) says is "immediate variable expansion" which is "expanded at time of parsing this line".  Unfortunately, it looks like the appending happens before the parsing.

I like the compartmentalized aspect of `.bbappend` but haven't found a way to refer to the `.bbappend` itself or if there is some other way to get the git info from the original layer. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can demonstrate the immediate expansion with the following demo. Edit
meta-yocto/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_%.bbappend which ships as part of the standard Yocto Project reference setup and add:

SOMEVAR := "${@bb.warn("${FILE}")}"

If you then run "bitbake -p" to reparse the metadata, it will show:

WARNING: /meta-yocto/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_%.bbappend

showing that it was run at the time the file was parsed. This is why you will sometimes see tricks like:

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${BPN}:

which is also in that bbappend. This adds a directory in that layer into the search path for files, which can then override the main recipe from the layer.